# Edit text in Listview Custom Adapter Loses its position while scrolling? - c# - Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin, xamarin.android

When we enter value in row 1 the value entered in row 1 is appearing back in row 6 when we scroll to the row 6. Please see the below code and advice.

```
namespace Kites
{
public class Marks 
{
    // add any if you need more

    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public string MarksScored { get; set; }
}

public class TEXTCHECK
{
    public int POS { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class MarksListViewAdapter : BaseAdapter<Marks>
{
    private List<Marks> mstuduentmarks;
    private List<TEXTCHECK> abc = new List<TEXTCHECK>();
    private Context mcontext;

    public MarksListViewAdapter (Context context, List<Marks> stud)
    {
        mstuduentmarks = stud;
        mcontext = context;
    }

    public override int Count 
    {
        get 
        {
            return mstuduentmarks.Count;
            //              return mattendence.Count;

        }
    }
    public override long GetItemId (int position)
    {
        return position;
    }
    public override Marks this[int position] 
    {
        get 
        {
            return mstuduentmarks [position];
            //              return mattendence [position];

        }
    }

    class ViewHolder : Java.Lang.Object
    {
        public EditText comsevin;
        public TextView namenmn;
    }

    public override View GetView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {

        ViewHolder holder;
        View view = convertView;

        if (view == null) // otherwise create a new one
        {
            view = LayoutInflater.From(mcontext).Inflate(Resource.Layout.listview_Marks, null, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.comsevin = view.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editTextTeacherMarks);
            holder.namenmn = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textStudentNameTeacherMarks);
            holder.namenmn.Tag = position;
            view.Tag = holder;
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder)view.Tag;
        }

        holder.namenmn.Text = mstuduentmarks[position].StudentName;

        int pos = (int)holder.namenmn.Tag;

        holder.comsevin.TextChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {
            abc[pos].Value = holder.comsevin.Text;
        };

        //TextView txtStudent = 
        //txtStudent.Text = mstuduentmarks[position].StudentName;


        //txtMarks.FocusChange += (object sender, View.FocusChangeEventArgs e) =>
        //{
        //      //txtMarks.RequestFocusFromTouch ();

        //      mstuduentmarks[position].MarksScored = txtMarks.Text;
        //};



        holder.comsevin.BeforeTextChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {
            abc.Add(new TEXTCHECK { POS = position, Value = mstuduentmarks[position].MarksScored }); 
        };
        holder.comsevin.AfterTextChanged += (sender, e) => 
        {
            int a = abc[pos].POS;
            mstuduentmarks[pos].MarksScored = abc[pos].Value;
        };


        //txtMarks.Tag = position;
        //txtMarks.TextChanged += TxtMarks_TextChanged;
        return view;
    }

    //void TxtMarks_TextChanged (object sender, Android.Text.TextChangedEventArgs e)
    //{
    //  EditText txtMarks = (EditText)sender;
    //  //var position = (int)txtMarks.Tag;



    //}
}
}
```

When we enter value in row 1 the value entered in row 1 is appearing back in row 6 when we scroll to the row 6. Please see the below code and advice.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, when experiencing lists that don't reflect the dataset  (experiencing item repetition for example) in listview / recyclerview it means that you're either using dirty views which were previously used and then uncorrectly Re-Bound, or simply using wrong positions during bind

I see where you are getting it wrong:

```
if (view == null) // otherwise create a new one
        {
            view = LayoutInflater.From(mcontext).Inflate(Resource.Layout.listview_Marks, null, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.comsevin = view.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editTextTeacherMarks);
            holder.namenmn = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textStudentNameTeacherMarks);


            holder.namenmn.Tag = position;//<------------here!!!
            view.Tag = holder;
        }
```

TLDR Don't save positions this way.

**Whats happening**: this instance of your view is being reused by listView, meaning that sometimes (many times) **if (view == null)** will be false and this means **Tag property will not be updated** for row 6 (or any other calls that will use recycled Views) and you are in fact using a dirty value.

You are then trying to use the Tag property as position, but forgetting this tag is already dirty if the view was recycled

```
int pos = (int)holder.namenmn.Tag;

        holder.comsevin.TextChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {
            abc[pos].Value = holder.comsevin.Text;
        };
```

Since you have access to the position in this method call you should use it directly

take a look at this [guide](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html) from Java Code geeks even though it's in Java you will be able to see a good implementation of the old ViewHolder/ListView pattern.

---

Hope this helps

Comment: @Harsh check the updated answer so you understand what went wrong ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help and understanding about my issue, Actually i tried using the position value directly but still i am getting the same issue.

Comment: @HarshBakshi you're welcome, I believe that everywhere you are using the variable "pos" you are getting a dirty value, can you delete the declaration of the variable and check that everywhere there is "pos" you change it to "position"?
Sorry for insisting, this is really easy to forget one , and that is enough for a bad Bind

Comment: erase this line please: int pos = (int)holder.namenmn.Tag;